# gettype() returns the type based on the variable type - how do I get the type based on the content?

Tags: php, casting

I'm trying to make a simple settings script, which basically send a setting name and a setting value to my database.

This is pretty simple actually - setting and getting this, requires little code and task is done.

But I would like the data to be returned with the correct type.
Using [gettype()](http://php.net/gettype) returns `string` every time - this is logical since the content returned from my database is a string.

This effect can be achieved by using [json_decode()](http://php.net/json_decode) on my content. This returns the type based on the content and it works like expected.

But do I have a better option?

I was considering assigning a type to my database table, but this just increases the complexity of setting and getting the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the any of the following php functions to check if a variable matches the formatting of a specific variable type:

is_numeric, is_bool, is_null, is_float, is_int, is_string, is_object, is_array

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for - I'm looking for something that doesn't increase the complexity (like adding a switch for checking and typecasting).

Comment: True, but its got to be more efficient than running json_decode(). You could also try something like mysql_field_type(), but that might not be as efficient as you are wanting either. You might have to hard-code the way you are handling each of the fields that are returned based on their array index to achieve maximum efficiency.

Comment: One of the issues with going with this solution, is that the string `true` will not evaluate as a true with `is_bool("true")` - but `is_string("true")` will. Which makes this not work for me.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer as the best alternative - it seems there are no better options.